# VBA: Multiple matching columns sorted based on a dummy

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, multiple-columns

I have a huge datasheet in excel, which i need sorted.
I need two columns to match based on a Dummy.
The dummy is either 'C'(call) or 'P'(put). The two other columns are 'expiration date' and 'strike price'.
I need to sort the datasheet so it is only containing C and P that have the same expiration date and strike price.

I've been trying go search the internet without any help. I can't really figure out how to program it in VBA.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to sort / filter / group your data? Could you please post some example?

Comment: @MátéJuhász , sorry for not explaining it thoroughly.
I want to filter the data based on the Call or Put. Meaning that I want to filter it so the Call option's strike price and expiration date is equal the Put option's strike price and expiration price.  
The Call and the Put is in 1 Column.
So is it possible to write a code saying:
If Strike price for C is equal Strike price for P and Expiration date for C is equal Expiration date for P it should keep those in the datasheet and if it's not equal then it should remove the row.

Hope this made it more clear.

Comment: Maybe you could hack up a row or two that shows what you are after and post a screenshot.  A picture is worth a 1000 words after all.

Comment: @Rossco , Sure: [link](http://i.imgur.com/etFEuQX.png)

So I want the P and the C to have the same expiration date and strike price. And if they don't have that, then the rows should be removed from the datasheet.

Comment: still not clear. Do you want to compare e.g. any "C" row whether it has corresponding "P" column and keep only if yes, or are you interested in rows next to each other only, eventually do you have other key column that need to match? How the macro should know which is "THE C" and which is "THE P" row??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I think: (I am addin a new column -column `W`- which is empty- to mark the row as "Matched" which is to be deleted after operation.)

First sub to mark the doublets (Matched Rows):

```
Private Sub FindDoublets()

    Dim intRowC As Long
    Dim intRowP As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    Range("W1").EntireColumn.Insert

    For intRowC = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(intRowC, 6).Value = "C" Then
            For intRowP = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If Cells(intRowP, 6).Value = "P" Then
                    If Cells(intRowC, 4).Value = Cells(intRowP, 4).Value And Cells(intRowC, 7).Value = Cells(intRowP, 7).Value Then
                        Cells(intRowC, 23).Value = "Matched"
                        Cells(intRowP, 23).Value = "Matched"
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Second sub to delete not matched so not marked rows:

```
Private Sub DeleteNotMatchedRows()

    Dim intRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For intRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(intRow, 23).Value <> "Matched" Then
            Rows(intRow).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next

    Range("W1").EntireColumn.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75536/discussion-on-answer-by-kitap-mitap-vba-multiple-matching-columns-sorted-based).

Answer (score 0):

In your example sheet enter this formula in column W: `=IF(F2="C",TRUE,FALSE)` and this one into column X: `=COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,G:G,G2,W:W,NOT(W2))`
Now you will have "1" in column X when actual row has a corresponding C / P row and "0" otherwise. Just need to filter for 0-s and delete the rows.
You can do the same with macro too but it's more complicated.